# K8 pods issues by using azure cli

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-cli

I'm trying to get the pod details in k8 by using azure cli. But I'm getting an error.
E0518 09:08:17.516637     243 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://auditboard-test-***********************:443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp: lookup auditboard-test-******************.io on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host

Can someone help me on this how to resolve such type of issue.

Thanks in advance.

E0518 09:08:17.516637     243 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://auditboard-test-***********************:443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp: lookup auditboard-test-******************.io on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host

Comment: What command are you running in the Azure CLI?
I'd expect you to be using kubectl, not the azure cli.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the pod details in k8 by using azure cli. But I'm getting an error. E0518 09:08:17.516637 243 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://auditboard-test-***********************:443/api?timeout=32s":dial tcp: lookup auditboard-test-******************.io on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host

I have followed the below steps to get all pods in **AKS** using **Azure CLI**.

Make sure that you have to use **kubectl** command to get the pod details in **Azure Cli**.

1. Login to your Azure account with the minimum required role is  **Reader** role permission.

   ```
   az login
   ```
2. Set the cluster subscription using the below command.

```
az account set --subscription <subscriptionID>
```

3. Download cluster credentials

```
    az aks get-credentials --resource-group <Resource-group-Name>> --name <AKSName>
```

4. Now, you can run kubectl command to get the Pod details in AKS.

```
kubectl get pods
```

[image]

You can also check the **pods** from **Azure portal** by navigating to the below steps.

**Azure portal > Kubernetes Services > Select your AKS > Workloads > Select your name space (where you deployed the pods>**

[image]

If still facing the same issue, check the below settings.

1. Double-check the hostname, and make sure there are no typos or missing characters.
2. Ensure that check the **DNS** configuration is correct and that the **DNS** server can resolve the hostname and then try using  `nslookup` to manually check if the hostname can be resolved to an IP address.

Reference:  [Install and Set Up kubectl on Linux](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/)

Comment: Thanks for info Venkat 
but actually the issue is untill 3 step it is done but when i calling the pods information i'm getting an issue

Comment: Kindly share the error and also try the same in Azure Cloud shell and share the result.

Comment: above are the error details

Comment: Kindly add the error screenshot to understand the issue clearly.